# File Stream not getting closed once I read the file at Application Launch in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, filestream, iostream

I have written a code to read and write a file. When I read the file using StreamReader in LoadFile Method and then next time when I call SaveFile Method and try to open StreamWriter my application is not able to open the file and throws an exception that file stream already in use. I have dispose the stream still the streams in Load method is not getting closed. Following is the code. Please tell me what wrong i am doing:

```
private async Task LoadFile()
        {
            assetFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Constants.LocalFolderForLog, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);


            using (Stream streamData = await assetFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(LogFile))
            {
                using (StreamReader writer = new StreamReader(streamData))
                {
                    Logger.Load(writer);
                    writer.Dispose();
                }

                streamData.Dispose();
            }


        }
```

---Save File

```
 public static async Task SaveFile()
        {
            //StorageFolder assetFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Constants.LocalFolderForLog, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            //var storageFile = await assetFolder.CreateFileAsync(
            //               LogFile,
            //               CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            using (Stream streamData = await assetFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(LogFile, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(streamData))
                {
                    Logger.Save(writer);

                    writer.Dispose();
                }

                streamData.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The whole point of the `using` statement is that you do not have to explicitly call `Dispose()` on your disposable objects. Your resources will be disposed as soon as they get out of scope (even  through an exception).

Comment: Yes i got your point but still I am not able to open a stream again if I call LoadFile method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a race due to the asynchronous opening of the stream.
Note, that using the asynchronous operation, control immediately  returns to the caller (the code which invoked `LoadFile()`, even though the operation is still going on in the background.
Make sure you `await` on your first Task, before invoking the second one.
You can find nice examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: I have awaited the call of both the methods. LoadFile I am calling on load of the page and Save I am calling when I am navigating away from the page.